# Pregunta sobre matriz en java

Tags: java, array, matrices

necesito hacer este ejercicio 
Realizar un Programa que permita llenar una matriz Cuadrada de NxN y se obtenga los siguientes Valores:

**1) Diagonal Principal y secundaria**

**2) Suma de elementos de cada fila**

**3) Valor de un elemento de la posición X(fila) y Y(columna)**

**4) Máximo elemento por fila**

**5) Porcentaje de Valores negativos por Columna**

La cosa es que para hacerlo necesito que la matriz sea n x n en java, y no logro hacerla.
Hasta ahora estoy intentando hacer la matriz n x n donde el usuario ingrese el tamaño y que tambien ingrese los valores para X y Y

tengo esto

```
package prueba2;

import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author _Victor_
 */
public class Prueba2 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int nelementosx = 0;
        int nelementosy = 0;

       nelementosx = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el tamaño para X"));
       nelementosy = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el tamaño para Y"));

       int [][] matriz = new int [nelementosx][nelementosy];
        // Hasta aqui esta el tamaño de la matriz nxn

        // Ingresar elementos

          System.out.println("Elija los numreos del arreglo");
           for (int i = 0; i < nelementosx; i++){
         System.out.println(" ");
         for (int j = 0; j < nelementosy; j++){
             System.out.println("-Digite un numero para X ");
         matriz[i] = entrada.nextInt();
             System.out.println("-Digite un numero para Y ");
         matriz[j] = entrada.nextInt();

           }

         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mas alla que no intentaste nada.. solo como ayuda, la matriz se carga con un solo valor.. ya que la estas recorriendo y sabes la posicion.. como matriz[i,j] = entrada.nextInt;

Comment: Buenas noches, la verdad es que si lo estoy intentando, solo que apenas entoy aprendidoendo arrays y mis conocimientos sobre este tema es poco, pero gracias igualmente :)

Comment: ok.. pero aca se pide que lo intentes y falles y vengas con todo lo que probaste y fallaste. Si no estariamos haciendo el ejercicio por ti. Con mucho gusto te ayudaremos y corregiremos (como hice ahi arriba), pero primero intentalo. Si solo copias la solucion, no vas a estar aprendiendo nada.

Comment: Yo recomiendo que te compres un libro de métodos númericos